# Superscript html tag in appendchild

Tags: javascript, html, dom

My js file exports on the frontend a text that contains a superscript tag. The problem is that on the browser the `<sup>` and the `&reg;` is not rendering and instead of the it shows the tag itself as text. Any solutions? Thanks!

```
var rName="Something<sup>&reg;</sup>";
var rURL="http://www.google.com";
var rAA=1;

function addResult(rName, rURL, rAA)
    {
        var node=document.createElement("li");
        var linkNode=document.createElement("a");

        node.setAttribute("id", rAA);
        node.setAttribute("class", "searchListing");
        node.setAttribute("onclick", "window.open('"+rURL+"','_self');");


        linkNode.setAttribute("href", rURL);
        linkNode.setAttribute("target", "_self");



        var textnode=document.createTextNode(rName);

        node.appendChild(textnode);

        document.getElementById("search_list_results").appendChild(node);
        document.getElementById(rAA).appendChild(linkNode);
    }
```

Comment: [jsFiddle demo of question](http://jsfiddle.net/u2f2K/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A text node does not contain HTML by definition, so any special HTML characters will be escaped and printed literally.

You can create a `span` element and set its `innerHTML`:

```
var spannode = document.createElement('span');
spannode.innerHTML = rName;
node.appendChild(spannode);
```

Comment: You saved the day. Thank you so much. Regards